# trouble converting object to float

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have an object that I would like to convert to a currency format:

```
df_final.sum_funded.head()

0     472161.07
1     719768.97
2      23148.11
3    1215078.15
4             0

Name: sum_funded, dtype: object
```

I've tried numerous iterations, including:

```
"${:,.0f}".format(df_final.sum_funded.astype(float) )
```

which produces the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-285-dd77177c4126> in <module>()
----> 1 "${:,.0f}".format(df_final.sum_funded.astype(float) )
  2 
  3 
  4 

ValueError: Unknown format code 'f' for object of type 'str'
```

Why is it converting it to `str` when I'm doing an explicit float conversion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're not passing a `float` to `format`, you're passing a `Series` to it. (A `Series` with `dtype=float` maybe, but still a `Series`.) There's no way to format a `Series` as a single number, because it's a whole bunch of numbers, so your code doesn't work.

If you're wondering why you get that specific error: the slightly oversimplified version is that for any object without a `__format__` method, Python does `obj.__str__().__format__(formatspec)`. So, the `Series` gets converted to a string, which it then tries to format as a float.

If you want to format *each value in the `Series`*, rather than the `Series` as a whole, you need to do that explicitly. For example, you can use `map` or `apply` (using the method `str.format` bound to the string `"${:,.0f}"` as a function):

```
print(df_final.sum_funded.map("${:,.0f}".format))
```

… or loop over the elements:

```
for elem in df_final.sum_funded:
    print("${:,.0f}".format(elem)
```

---

With operators like `+`, and methods on Pandas (and Numpy/Scipy) objects, and functions that come out of Pandas (or Numpy or Scipy), things usually just work like magic—if you give them a single value, they work on a single value; if you give them an Series or DataFrame or array, they work on every element. And if you write your own function that does nothing but operators and Pandas functions and methods, it works like magic too.

But with functions and methods that *don't* come from Pandas (or Numpy or Scipy) and try to do anything other than operators and Pandas functions, like `str.format`, this doesn't happen. They weren't written to work elementwise, and there's no way for Pandas to automatically hook them. So, if you want to map them across a whole Series (etc.), you have to explicitly ask for that.

That's what Pandas' [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) and [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html#pandas.Series.apply) and similar methods are for. Or you can go the other way and use Numpy's [`vectorize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) to turn a normal dumb Python function into a Numpy/Pandas elementwise function. Or you can just loop manually. But the point is, you need to do *something*.

Comment: Thanks! One follow up, what do you mean by format "the series as a whole" . now that i see your answer, this is what i was trying to do, and it doesn't make sense...

Comment: @DerekKrantz Let me edit the answer to explain a bit more about what I think is confusing you.

Comment: @abarbert thanks for the thoughtful explanation. makes sense now

Answer (score 2):

You have to use pandas Series's `map` function to apply the formatter on **each** element.

```
df_final.sum_funded.map("${:,.0f}".format)
```